# After the data is imported into the mysql table, it shows abnormal

Tags: mysql, load, local, display

MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual

3.3.4.9 Using More Than one Table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'event.txt' INTO TABLE event;
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the problem is in the parsing of event.txt. Make sure all the field delimiters and record delimiters are what you expect.

Comment: Indeed,the txt file on Windows need to use \r\n as a line terminator.